# rhel repositories with gstreamer-plugins-ugly

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, gstreamer, rhythmbox

What yum repository provides gstreamer-plugins-ugly (or/and other gstreamer plugins) for Red Hat Linux 6? And do repositories for CentOS and Fedora suit for Red Hat?

Reason of this question is that explicit query of RHEL repositories in Google leads to CentOS and Fedora repositories but as far as I know problems with binary compatibility between same applications in different Linux distributions may occur. Is that correct?

Comment: CentOS's reason for existance is being binary-compatible to RHEL, though it's usually used in the other direction, so I'd be carefully optimistic.

Comment: You mean RHEL packages are usually being installed in CentOS?

Comment: well, people will run (commercial closed-source) software that is only certified to work with RHEL on CentOS and not usually have too many problems.

Comment: Hmm... I should try it later. Thanks for quick reply: one secret is revealed for me now :)  http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/

Comment: I was late to edit previous comment. I wanted to say that I have found one repo with ugly gstreamer for RHEL6:  http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/linuxtech/el6/testing/
 But I am not sure that this format of repo name is proper. For this comment to be useful for other people might I ask how this repo should be properly added to replolist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

´gstreamer-plugins-ugly' : You can search http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3 and see the available repo´s : rpmfusion.repo, el.repo, nux.repo, atrpms.repo, repoforge.repo (= rpmforge.repo ).

One is compatible with the Redhat repo : That's rpmfusion : http://rpmfusion.org/ >>> http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
The other can cause trouble at an update. ( # yum update ).

---